# Cannot instantiate a List<String>

Tags: java

I'm trying to instantiate a List of type String and when I have this;

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I get a compile time error saying the types are incompatible but as far as I'm aware this is how you're supposed to instantiate a List.

This is the full class.

```
package listDriver;
import list.*;

/**
 * Test the List ADT.
 * 
 * @author (sdb) 
 * @version (Jan 2012)
 */
public class HomeworkArrayListDriver
{
    public static void main()
    {   
        List <String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println ("Testing ArrayLists");
        //names = new ArrayList <String> ();
        names.add ("jim");
        names.add ("mary");
        names.add ("joe");
        names.add ("sue");
        System.out.println (names.get(2));  // Should be joe
        names.set (2, "Joe");            
        System.out.println (names.get(2));  // Should be Joe
        System.out.println (names.size());  // Should be 4
        names.remove (0);
        System.out.println (names.size());  // Should be 3
        names.add(0,"joe");
        System.out.println (names.size());  // Should be 4
        System.out.println (names.get(3));  // Should be sue
        if (names.isEmpty())
            System.err.println ("Incorrect, error in isEmpty");
        names.clear();
        if (!names.isEmpty())
            System.err.println ("Incorrect, error in isEmpty or clear");

    }

}
```

Comment: Looms like you have a space between `List` and `<String>`

Comment: @tgdavies That makes no difference at all.

Comment: `import java.util.List;` and `import java.util.ArrayList;` .. Your import seems bad

Comment: Did you import `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`, or are you using your own versions of these?

Comment: You'll need to show us your "List ADT" classes

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your imports are wrong.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("3")
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using your own ADT (which people seem to be alluding to), this wont help you. In this case (1) Make sure that your ArrayList implementation satisfies your List interface (2) Make sure both of those are accessible via `import list.*`

Answer (score -1):

Make your `ArrayList` class in your `list` package implement the `List` class in your `list` package.

Comment: Actually I think this may be the correct answer -- it looks like the OP is using their own List and ArrayList implementations -- if that's what they want to do, we need to see the source code for them.

Comment: @tgdavies. Thanks. People are downvoting the answers and yet not providing any reasons. I can correct or update the answer based on the feedback. We don't want to leave the future readers of this answer wondering why the answer was incorrect when it is not incorrect.

Comment: @mikenaples, did you try this recommendation?